# Requery text boxes on a subform in Access

Tags: ms-access

Good morning, I am developing an access database for use in Nepali schools.
I have a form (the main form) with a subform (frmStudsTakingTTsv2) and 12 textboxes on the subform txtSubA_(i).

I am unable to make a textbox perform a Refresh in VBa . This follows a series of action queries that are working well, these are in an AfterUpdate event on a combo box in the main form.
The text boxes are filled from expression builder and so need to be requeryed. The code in there is identical but textboxes on the main form change their contents – so each text box holds a different result.

What I have tried:

A -

```
frmStudsTakingTTsv2. & "txtSubA_trim(str(i)).Requery
```

the compiler does not like the &

B – using a string

```
Where = "Form.frmStudsTakingTTsv2.txtSubA_" & Trim(Str(i))
Me(Where).Requery
```

Produces run time error 2465 Can not find the field referred to in the expression

C – Then tried this

```
Dim crtlWhere As Control
Set crtlWhere = frmStudsTakingTTsv2.txtsubA_ & (i)
Me(crtlWhere).Requery
```

On Load event – method or member not found

D – Next

```
Set crtlWhere = frmStudsTakingTTsv2
Location = ".txtSubA_" & Trim(Str(i)) – this is fine
Me(crtlWhere & Location).Requery
```

Error 450 wrong number of arguments

E – Next

```
Me.Controls(crtlWhere & Location).Requery
```

Error 450 wrong number of arguments

Just to add this site has been v useful, offering solutions over the years.

Comment: Gustav - thank you - opened the door for me,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
Me!frmStudsTakingTTsv2.Form.Controls("txtsubA_" & Cstr(i)).Requery
```

where `frmStudsTakingTTsv2` is the name of the subform *control*.